# SetTimer returning non-zero but its not the id i supplied, and my callback never triggers

Tags: winapi

I have setup a message loop.

I call `SetTimer` like this:

```
SetTimer(null, 5, 1000, timerFunc_c);
```

The return value of this is a random number like `11422`. And it never triggers my callback. If i set timer like this:

```
SetTimer(msgWinHwnd, 5, 1000, timerFunc_c);
```

Then it returns 0 and it then makes `GetMessage` with 0 for min and max, trip with WM_TIME message, however my callback is never called.

Do you know why in first situation my callback does not return the id i told it? And why it never fires the callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour for the `SetTimer` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx):

> nIDEvent [in]
>
> Type: UINT_PTR
>
> A nonzero timer identifier. If the hWnd
>   parameter is NULL, and the nIDEvent does not match an existing timer
>   then it is ignored and a new timer ID is generated

If your callback isn't ever called (it's hard to tell for sure from your question), check your `GetMessage` loop and make sure you're not specifying a window filter (e.g. you should be calling `GetMessage(&msg, 0, ...);` rather than `GetMessage(&msg, msgWinHwnd, ...);`.

Comment: Ah thanks Jonathan! My GetMessage is calling `GetMessage(&msg, msgWinHwnd, 0, 0)`. But even when I set GetMessage to null hwnd, its not triggering the callback, its just triggering the WM_TIMER event. I do notice something funny, my `DispatchEvent` is not triggering the `WNDPROC` of my msgWinHwnd, is that normal?